# Still possible to download Windows Phone 8/8.1 apps?

Tags: 8.1, 8.0, apps, downloads

Is there anywhere to find *and* download Windows Phone 8/8.1 apps?

I haven't been able to find anywhere to download them.

Comment: There are websites like https://www.appx4fun.com/ that let you download apps in XAP/APPX format, but I'm not sure if it's possible to actually install them in a phone without using the Store app. Also, it's very much possible the download links themselves (usually hosted on 3rd-party file sharing sites) have expired.

Comment: Found a link to a Telegram group from AAWP, where you're supposed to be able to download XAPs: https://t.me/W8Mobile . I haven't checked it myself as I don't use Telegram, nor WP 8.1, but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: Trying out the Telegram group now..

Answer (score 4):

No, the Windows Store closed for Windows 8.1 closed last December. Officially, the OS fell out of support back in July 2017.

Comment: Thanks..I guess my question was more about whether there are unofficial channels still hosting old apps.  Maybe in forums or on BitTorrent perhaps, maintained by enthusiasts and former developers..?

Answer (score 2):

I have never did it, but you can deploy xap files, and you need to developer unlocked your phone, I recommend see here: https://www.techmesto.com/developer-unlock-windows-phone/